# How can i get 3 table data in index in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables  schools, school_Details,ratings

** Schools**

- id
- name
- phone
- school
- email
- status

**School details**:

-id

- school_id
- image
- status

**ratings**:

-id

- school_id
- rating_value
- status

both rating &school details have only one row for one school_id.

Now how can i get all details from all 3 tables in index from schoolController

Answer (score 2):

Use Laravel Relationship.

In Schools Model add this.

```
public function schoolDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\SchoolDetails');
}

public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ratings');
}
```

---

In School Details Model add this.

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}
```

---

In Ratings Model add this.

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}
```

---

In School Controller

```
public function index()
{
   $schools = Schools::with('schoolDetails')
                     ->with(ratings)
                     ->get();
   return $schools;
}
```

Can you try this,

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty wide question.  It would help to show what you've tried so far.  The answer is to create [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationships from schools to details and ratings.

And then call those relations within the base school object from your index method.  You can even [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) these for one simple and clean pull from the database.

To clarify, from your **School model**:

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
}
```

And same thing for your school details.  Then, to eager load in your index method:

```
$schools= App\School::with(['ratings', 'details'])->get();
```

Then your school object has all you've asked for:

```
$school->ratings->status
```

etc.